# Post- and Preconditions

Tags: c#, preconditions, bosque

I was just reading the documentation for the Bosque Programming Language and came across [section 12](https://github.com/Microsoft/BosqueLanguage/blob/master/docs/language/overview.md#0.12-Errors-and-Checks) about errors and checks

I was wondering if C# has a similar concept to post and preconditions.
At first glimpse, I thought that this looks like guard clauses but from a Language perspective, one isn't entering the method at all with these preconditions.

*Since the documentation is fairly new I will post the source code which I am talking about here:*

```
entity Foo {
    field x: Int;

    invariant x > 0; //check whenever a Foo is constructed

    method m(y: Int): Int
        requires y >= 0; //precondition
        ensures _result_ > 0; //postcondition
    {
        check this.x - y > 0;   //sanity check - enabled on optimized builds
        assert this.x * y != 0; //diagnostic assert - only for test/debug

        return x * y;
    }
}
```

In C# I would normally write something like this

```
internal class Foo 
{
    private int x;

    public int  m(int y)
    {
        if(y<0) //Negative guard clause
        {
            //throw an exception
        }
        //Assertions 
        int result = x * y;

        if(result<0)
        {
            //throw an exception
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

While writing this question I came across code contracts in C# which act in a similar way than guard clauses it seems. `Contract.Requires` in C# looks to me more like the `check` and `assert` statements inside of the method.

So my question is:
Is there a similar concept which executes before entering the method or in the case of the postcondition afterwards?

Comment: What exactly is Bosque's behavior when it comes to preconditions, if the method is not to be entered? Exception?

Comment: You're looking for [Code Contracts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/code-contracts).